# 500 Internal server error in CRUD with Firebird

Tags: codeigniter, firebird, crud

I have installed CRUD application in my CI.I am using Firebird database.The connection is fine while i am testing :

```
$res= $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ADMIN_USER');
var_dump($res->row());
```

this is returning result.

but while i an using crud function:

```
public function admin()
{
 try{
  $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

   $crud->set_theme('datatables');
   $crud->set_table('ADMIN_USER');
   $crud->columns('USERNAME','PASSWORD');

   $output = $crud->render();
   var_dump($output);
   $this->_example_output($output);

}catch(Exception $e){
 show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
}
}
```

no result is coming..and "500Internal Server Error" is showing in firebug..
The actual error shown:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The table name does not exist. Please check you database and try again. --- 
#0 C:\wamp\www\anuncio\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php(4420): Grocery_CRUD->get_table() 
#1 C:\wamp\www\anuncio\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php(4436): Grocery_CRUD->pre_render() 
#2 C:\wamp\www\anuncio\application\controllers\examples.php(27): Grocery_CRUD->render() 
#3 [internal function]: Examples->admin() 
#4 C:\wamp\www\anuncio\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#5 C:\wamp\www\anuncio\index.php(202): require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\anu...') 
#6 {main}
```

I am new in CI, grocery CRUD and Firebird..Cant solve this error.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, your table does not exist. To be more specific, the table ADMIN_USER does not exist.

Comment: I told in my post while I am fetch data using $this->db->query i am getting result..So my table exists.

Comment: Your error says different, is your theme right?  Whats is the result? Is it really data from that table?
--> your error -->
The table name does not exist. Please check you database and try again. --- #0

Comment: even if i remove the theme and just try to print the output same error is showing.

Comment: Thats a shame. Good luck with something else then!

Comment: You might want to mark the question as solved then, but that's up to you.